# C error:storage size of ffblk isn't known

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <dirent.h>

struct ffblk ffblk;

int main()
{
   printf("Successfully made ffblk");
}
```

At the moment, all I'm trying to do is make the structure ffblk. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ffblk {
  char lfn_magic[6] __attribute__((packed));                
  short lfn_handle __attribute__((packed));               
  unsigned short lfn_ctime __attribute__((packed));     
  unsigned short lfn_cdate __attribute__((packed));     
  unsigned short lfn_atime __attribute__((packed));     
  unsigned short lfn_adate __attribute__((packed));     
  char _ff_reserved[5] __attribute__((packed));
  unsigned char  ff_attrib __attribute__((packed));
  unsigned short ff_ftime __attribute__((packed));
  unsigned short ff_fdate __attribute__((packed));
  unsigned long  ff_fsize __attribute__((packed));
  char ff_name[260] __attribute__((packed));
};
```

This is a copy of struct ffblk from an old `dir.h` file - meant for dos I believe.

I do not know what you are doing but you really should find an appropriate version of this object for your system.  Your code might possibly compile using this definition of struct ffblk, but I would doubt its integrity.  It appears that your system's `dir.h` file does know about this struct.  Try editing the `dos.h` and `dir.h` files to see what is going on.

For example, you may need to define something to get the struct included correctly. Sometimes changing the order of header files in  program code can clear up this kind of problem.